# Multiple compound comparison in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which is getting options (using getopts). Let say they are '-n' , '-d' , '-u' . I only want to have one of the option being chosen, if not, it will prompt the user error.

The code is like this:

```
    while getopts ":dun" name; do

            case $name in

              d  )
                    DELETE='YES'
                    ;;
              u  )
                    UPDATE='YES'
                    ;;
              n  )
                    NEW='YES'
                    ;;
            esac
     done
```

I can only have **$DELETE** or **$UPDATE** or **$NEW** being 'YES' in one time, meaning the user cannot specific '-n' and '-d' in the same time or '-u' and '-n' in the same time, how do I achieve that in a IF statement ?

I have been looking for this in stackoverflow, but can't find any. Thanks for the help, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete hack, and depends on the option variables being either unset or "YES" (and in the form I've written it, is bash-only):

```
if [[ "$DELETE$UPDATE$NEW" == YESYES* ]]; then
    echo "Please only use one of -d, -u, and -n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

(If you were using the brand-x shell instead of bash, it'd be something like `if [ "$DELETE$UPDATE$NEW" = "YESYES" -o "$DELETE$UPDATE$NEW" = "YESYESYES" ]; then`)

Comment: This is a smart hack! I will never thought of that even in a million year :D Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 2):

You can increment a counter every time getopts() senses one of the valid commandline options.  Then, after the loop test the counter's value.  If it is greater than one, then multiple options were specified.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off setting your variables to `true` or `false`, so you can simply write

```
if $DELETE; then
  echo "You've already specified UPDATE!"
fi
```

and similar.

However, options are called that because they are supposed to be *optional*, and usually orthogonal. (There are a few instances where options of common utilities exclude each other, but the vast majority don't). What you want is really a mandatory mode of operation, so you shouldn't receive it as an option at all, but simply as the first command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some getopt-kludge to manage having only one of the option being chosen.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -u)
            echo "got -u"
            break
            ;;
        -d)
            echo "got -d"
            break
            ;;
        -n)
            echo "got -n"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "some error"
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```